# Is it cheaper to store data across multiple instances of the same contract?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

From what I understand, code is deduplicated on the Ethereum blockchain by storing pointers in new blocks to blocks containing code that is being reused in the new block.

If that's the case:

1. **Is it better to store a new instance of a contract for each set of data (for example, information about a user), or...**
2. **better to have just *one* contract that stores all data in a data structure like an array of objects (for example, storing information about *all* users in one contract**.

To clarify with some incorrect pseudo code, should I store my information like this?

```
contract Whatever {
  Users = [
   {}, {}, {}, {}
  ]
}
```

or like this:

```
// User 1
contract Whatever {}

// User 2
contract Whatever {}

// User 3
contract Whatever {}

// etc.
```